# Why should I run a java class after generating jar file with maven package?

Tags: java, maven, packaging

I'm new to jar files and maven and trying to understand the use of Maven.
In this [Maven in 5 minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) article, we create the my-app project using maven and the directory structure looks like this:

```
my-app
|-- pom.xml
 -- src
    |-- main
    |   -- java
    |       -- com
    |           -- mycompany
    |               -- app
    |                   -- App.java
     -- test
         -- java
             -- com
                 -- mycompany
                     -- app
                         -- AppTest.java
```

Then we use 1. `mvn package` followed by 2. `java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App` which runs our App.java class.

My understanding is that 1. creates a new 'target' directory and inside it the jar file. And we use 2. to run the App class using the jar file. My question is, why did we run the App class in this way? Why is it better than just going to src/main/java/com/mycompany/app and compiling it and running `java App.java` ? Maybe I don't understand benefit of packaging. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Someone may expand, but the next thing to look at would be jar file manifests wherein you can specify the class to be run during packaging. It shortens the run command and allows someone to run your jar without knowledge of the contents.

Comment: First, you can't execute a source file directly (unless it's a _single_ source file, and then only if you're using a more recent version of Java). You first _compile_ the source files into class files, which contain the JVM byte-code which the JVM can then execute (this is what gives you the cross-platform functionality of Java). But now you have a bunch of class files, and that's not conducive to distribution. A JAR file is a (ZIP) file that packages all the class files and other resources into a single file, which is much easier to distribute.

Comment: Though typically, if you can _execute_ the program contained within a JAR file, then you'd create an _executable JAR file_. That's simply a JAR file with a `Main-Class` entry in the `MANIFEST.MF` file (look up how to set the main class via Maven). Then you can run the application using `java -jar <jar-file>`. Also, keep in mind that Maven is only a build tool (one of a few popular ones in the Java ecosystem). It is not _required_ to compile/package/build an application, but it does make things much easier and more repeatable.

Comment: The ability to invoke java directly on a single source file is very new and Maven is very, very old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know the answer of Why, you need to understand following things first:

1. How to compile a Java program and how to run the compiled java program (especially program declared inside a package)
   If you have java class `Test` inside package `hello`, you can compile it using `javac hello\Test.java` and run it using `java hello.Test` (i.e. we use fully qualified name to run a program and can not run it like `java Test`, it will give you error "could not find or load main class Test")

   So, just going to src/main/java/com/mycompany/app and running `java App.java` won't work but from src/main/java folder you can run it like `com.mycompany.app.App`
2. What is jar packaging.
   `jar` i.e. Java archive is nothing but a zip file aggregating all the java classes so that it can be distributed as a single unit.
3. Classpath
   Classpath is the place where java will look for the compiled classes
4. How to run a program which depends on Java classes in other jar files
   Suppose if my Test class depends on class XYZ which is inside the
   abc.jar file, then we need to tell java that search this abc.jar for
   dependencies (include this jar in classpath). This can be done using command `java -cp abc.jar hello.Test` here `-cp` option is nothing but a classpath and is used to tell java about directories or archives in which classes could be found. This command can be used when Test class is inside jar file like in your case
5. Maven
   If you have understood the above things then you would know that Maven has nothing to do with running your program. It is just a build tool which helps build the jar file from you code and helps in executing/organizing different tasks apart from build like clean, running tests, etc.

Comment: Sorry, it's because "going to src/main/java/com/mycompany/app and running java App.java " worked is why I asked that question. I hadn't used Java in a few years so I forgot that the classic way to run a class is to use javac to compile and then run the compiled version. However, the former had also worked somehow, hence found itself in my answer.

Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: May be you are using version >= 11 which gives you feature to run a single file source code. Java compiles the source file in memory and then runs the main method. But it's limited to Single source file i.e. all your source code is in single file. It also explains the .java extension allowed in java command

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn package
```

Maven is one of the package management tools for java.. the flag package, packages the app. It's used to declare deps for a project, package a project, build a project, and install binaries to a place(~/.m2/xx/..) where they can be read by java processes.

```
java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Runs the app, invoke main class of the app, -cp stands for classPath

Comment: Does this do anything to answer the ("why") question?

Comment: @clwhisk The question is this "Why should I run a java class after generating jar file with maven package?".  My answer is we build the project to package it as a jar, and java is to run packaged app.  It's lot more than that... this what I would try to understand first "package management, wether it's apt-ge install, yum install, brew install, npm install....etc " and then learn more form there.

Comment: @ItDepends uw...btw, it's always good to accept an answer, if you like/benefited from any of the answers.

Comment: @zatef Also, where is a good place to start understanding "package management" more?

Comment: When I am learning something new,I usually go with their getting-started https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/ @ItDepends

Answer (score 0):

Maven not just a packaging tool but also managing dependencies.

If your project is simple with no dependency/no import other package, you can "just going to src/main/java/com/mycompany/app and running `java App.java`". If it is not the case, you can't do it (try it)

`maven package` will export/copy dependencies to `target` folder so that JDK can find required classes and you can use it easily

Comment: This is one of the simplest answers, which is why it helps a lot. Thank you. (I'm sure there's a lot to take from the other answers as well!)